# How to make good matrix and give bold the mathematics expression in Overleaf?

Tags: math, matrix, latex, bold, overleaf

I want to make a matrix looks good in Overleaf. However, for some reason, the last entry is not centred. How to fix it? Also, in the inline mathematics expression, why I cannot bold the expression?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{gather}
\textbf{Y} = 

\begin{pmatrix}
$\textbf{Y_1}$\\
$\textbf{Y_2}$\\
$\vdots$        \\
$\textbf{Y_S}$
\end{pmatrix},

\textbf{U} = 

\begin{pmatrix}
$\textbf{U_{1,s}}$\\
$\textbf{U_{2,s}}$\\
$\vdots$        \\
$\textbf{U_{10,s}}$
\end{pmatrix}, 

\textbf{$\beta$} = 

\begin{pmatrix}
$\beta_{0,s}$\\
$\beta_{1,s}$\\
$\vdots$        \\
$\beta_{10,s}$
\end{pmatrix},
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

where

```
\textbf{$Y_s$} $= (y_{1,s}, y_{2,s}, …, y_{G, s})$, and $\textbf{$U_m$}$ $= 
(u_{1,m, s}, u_{2,m, s}, ..., u_{G,m, s}).$
```

It results like this

[image]

The variable beta should be bold, also Y_S and U_M after "where." Please help. Thank you

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I do  not understand, can't you run the codes I include in this question already?

Comment: No. The code in the question does not have a documentclass and everything else necessary for a document.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have added the standard document class and the package.

Comment: Does not compile